# org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '415

Tags: http, cxf, apache-camel

I am trying to call an external webservice running outside my machine and i have written the rout logic using camel framework

**Routing Code:**

```
from("direct:test1").process(new Processor() {                                       
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
        arg0.getOut().setBody("testmessage");
    }
}).to("cxf://http://localhost:8085/FinEdge-General/xrmServices/2011/Organization.svc?serviceClass=com.hcl.flsl.integration.msdn.crmwcf.IOrganizationService&defaultOperationName=Retrieve")
```

But when i execute the program i am getting the below error.

**Error**

> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '415:
>   Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml;
>   charset=UTF-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8'.' when communicating with
>   \\http://localhost:port/FinEdge-General/xrmServices/2011/Organization.svc

Note: Webservice is developed in .NET(WCF) and SOAP 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the CXF is sending the message with SOAP 1.1, you need to let it switch to SOAP 1.2 by apply the WSDL file as the serviceClass you use is not has that information.

BTW, you can find difference between the SOAP 1.1 message and SOAP 1.2 message [here](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/switch_soap11_to_soap12).

Answer (score 0):

As @Willem Jiang mentioned, you have to change the SOAP version to 1.2 . I do it programmatically:

```
service = Service.create("your service name");
service.addPort("your port", SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING, "your url");
```